# awk FS is a regular expression

Tags: bash, awk

My problem is the inability to output the treated file with the FS set as a regular expression.
I have a file that I have to treat:

```
id 1:1 2:1 3:2 5:1
id 1:2 3:1 4:1
```

Where I want to multiply a value (after ':') by 2:

```
id 1:2 2:2 3:4 5:2
id 1:4 3:2 4:2
```

I tried :

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=" [[:digit:]]+:"}{OFS=FS}{for (i=2; i<=NR;i++) $i=$i*2; print}' file
```

However, it gives me the literal  `[[:digit:]]+:` as the FS. I red a similar question here and tried to set fields as records, printing `$0, RT` at the end, but it also didn't work.

Thanks for any tips.

Comment: Which awk are you using?

Comment: @JamesBrown It doesn't matter there you can't set OFS to unknown digits.

Comment: @123 Don't spoil it. I only read the first sentence. :D

Answer (score 4):

You can use `split` function

```
$ awk '{for(i=2; i<=NF; i++){split($i,a,":"); a[2]*=2; $i=a[1]":"a[2]}} 1' file
id 1:2 2:2 3:4 5:2
id 1:4 3:2 4:2
```

Or a simpler `perl` solution, where all numbers after `:` are multiplied by `2`

```
$ perl -pe 's/:\K\d+/$&*2/ge' file
id 1:2 2:2 3:4 5:2
id 1:4 3:2 4:2
```

Comment: @Sundeep, why the final 1?

Comment: @airos Any nonzero number evaluates to true in awk and the default action if no block is specified after a condition is to print. So basically it just prints the lines.

Answer (score 2):

With gawk you can capture the field separators (analogous to `RT`) in the gawk-only extra argument to the split function:

```
BEGIN {FS=" [[:digit:]]+:"}

{
    split($0,a,FS,seps);
    printf "%s", a[1];
    for (i=2; i<=length(a); ++i)
      {printf "%s%s", seps[i-1], a[i]*2}
    print ""
}

$ awk -f mirr.awk mirr.txt
id 1:2 2:2 3:4 5:2
id 1:4 3:2 4:2
```